# Hyperlinks from rows in Mysql Table

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

The thing is that I have made application form which saves in db. And I want on other page to display just some rows of the mysql table in php table where the first column is hyperlink to the single application as it is in the form. My question is how it can automatically make hyperlinks and pages for each form?

This is my code for now

```
mysql_connect("host", "user", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error()); 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM applications ") or die(mysql_error()); 
echo ' <table width="760" border=1>
                    <tr> 
                        <th>Заявление<br>От дата:</th> 
                        <th>От/До</th>
                        <th>Статус</th>
                    </tr>';
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
        { 
             echo  '
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="applications.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">'.$info['today'] .'</a></td>  
                        <td>От '.$info['data1data'] .'.'.$info['data1mesec'] .'.'.$info['data1god'] .' до '.$info['data2data'] .'.'.$info['data2mesec'] .'.'.$info['data2god'] .' </td>
                        <td>';
                            if($info['status'] == 1) {
                                echo '<img src="Images/approved.jpg" />';
                            }
                            else {
                                echo '<img src="Images/declined.jpg" />';
                            }

            echo '          </td>
                    </tr> ';
        } 
echo '</table>';
```

The result I am trying to get is a table with 3 columns and rows for every application and from the first column of the application I get redirected to a single webpage for that application form and this link to be auto made by code something like "applications.php?id=[application id]"

Comment: so whats the problem get the id $_REQUEST['id'] on next page your application.php and do your stuff

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand so much but:

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM applications");
while($t = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  echo '<a href="'.$t['hyperlink'].'">'.$t['name'].'</a><br/>';
}
?>
```

Don't know what's the problem.

Comment: I want the code to simply made himself the link I can get redirected to the page (Which is also made by himself) which will be exact the same for each application except the values from the table